# Open a Chrome tab , based on a value from a website

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, tabs

I`m a newbie with programming but willing to learn ,

I need to make an extension for Chrome that searches for a value in a website , then opens another tab/link with the value from the initial page .

For example ,  if I visit a webpage and the field "Idkey00=maplesyrup' is in the source code ,  i need it to open automatically  another URL in different tab  with the Idkey00 value in it like :   http://mywebsite.com/maplesyrup/bla/bla.doc

Can you give me some help please? 
I could do it manually but it would take forever..

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to do it with [TamperMonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo), and you [should be able to use](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_location.asp) `window.location` to find out what the URL is.